# How to assign a ToolTip for the first column data in the GridView using a ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `ListBox` with number of items matching the number of rows in the `GridView`. Using this `ListBox` I want to display a tooltip for each row only to the first column data in the `GridView`. I have bound the `GridView` in the front end.

The code I have tried is giving **Index of out range** error :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                String ProCol = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].ToString();

                if (ProCol.Length != 0)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = ListBox1.Items[i].ToString().Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your code to the `DataBound` event on the `GridView` instead of doing the work in `RowDataBound`. That way, it will only run once when all the rows have been bound and the `GridView.Rows` collection has been initialized.

Also, you should do what **Michal Klouda** wrote in his answer regarding `<=` an `<`.

And you must make sure that the `ListBox1` has been databound before you bind the `GridView`.

Sample code that should work as long as you bind the `ListBox` befor the `GridView`:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gv = (GridView)sender;
    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var oneRow = gv.Rows[i];
        String ProCol = oneRow.Cells[0].ToString();

        if (ProCol.Length != 0)
        {
            oneRow.Cells[0].ToolTip = ListBox1.Items[i].ToString().Trim();
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It fails in the last iteration of your for cycle, since the index is zero based (first item has 0 index, last item has `count-1` index). Replace

```
i <= GridView1.Rows.Count
```

with

```
i < GridView1.Rows.Count
```

Comment: The GridView1.Rows.Count is 0 for me and so it does enter the loop here.

Comment: It does enter the loop, since 0 <= 0. Anyhow you will need to investigate why your row count is zero.. Which is quite important fact and you forgot to mention it in the question.